# In $F=Ma$,if our system (say a box 14kg) consists of a body 4kg then in the equation why don’t we write MA as 14a then 10a?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

https://ibb.co/nQTep6

This is our question.

https://ibb.co/jQCQwm

Now in the solution,at the very end of it there’s an equation of the box which is like
T-30g-60g=30a
My question is the man and the box are the system when we write equation of box then why don’t In F=Ma we use 90a instead of 30a?

Comment: That is just the equation of motion for the box.  The sum of the forces on the box equals the mass of the box times the acceleration of the box.  There is a separate equation of motion for the man.  The reason for writing two separate equations of motion even though both objects move together is that you want to get the internal force between the objects.

Comment: So I can do that? Write both mass of man and box as one?

Comment: I assumed that when box goes down,the man goes up so that’s why we've written different equations-can this be a reason for it too?

Comment: No, the man always remains on the bottom of the box.  He cannot lift himself off the bottom of the box no matter how hard he pulls on the rope, because he is more massive than the box, and the rope pulls on each of them equally.

Comment: I get it,just need a bit more clarification as to why didn’t we write 90a instead of 30a when it’s obvious that if we take the box as our system,it’s mass is 90Kg

Comment: You can choose to write the equation of motion for the man, for the box, or for both together.  The equation you're referring to is the equation of motion for the box alone.  The forces on the box are T (tension in the rope pulling up on the top of the box), -30g (weight of the box), and -60g (force exerted on the box by the man's feet).  The mass of the box is 30 kg.  Hence 30a.

Answer (score 0):

Do the two free body diagrams. One for the person (left) and one of the box (right)

[image: fbd]

And the corresponding equations of motion:

$$\begin{aligned}
  T + N - 60 g & = 60 a \\
  T- N - 30 g & = 30 a 
\end{aligned}$$

The second question states that $N=60 g$ such that the person feels their weight from the floor. This is achieved when

$$ \begin{cases} T = 180 g \\ a = 3 g \end{cases} $$

The point being that when doing free body diagrams *you must consider each body in isolation* with forces where contact or other interactions occur.